# How to put a Access Table into a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, ms-access

I have a MS-Access table in my database called "RichtingEnJaar".

This table has 2 columns: the "ID" and "Naam".

I need to get the whole column "Naam" to be in an array in C#.

I tried a lot already but can't seem to find the correct answer.

Can any of you help me out real quick?

```
connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Project Officieel\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project.accdb";

connect.Open();

OleDbCommand cmdKlassen = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Naam FROM RichtingEnJaar WHERE ID = 1", connect);

if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{    
    try
    {
                   OleDbDataReader KlasReader = null;
                   KlasReader = cmdKlassen.ExecuteReader();

                   while (KlasReader.Read())
                   {
                      Klas[0].Naam = KlasReader["Naam"].ToString();
                   }

                   connect.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception expe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
        connect.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
}
```

Tried a new one:

```
string connStringKlas = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Project Officieel\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project.accdb";

        DataTable resultsKlas = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection connKlas = new OleDbConnection(connStringKlas))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmdKlas = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Naam FROM RichtingEnJaar", connKlas);

            connKlas.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdKlas);

            adapter.Fill(resultsKlas);

            for (int i = 0; i <= resultsKlas.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Klas[i].Naam = resultsKlas.Rows[i].ToString();
            }

            connKlas.Close();
        }

        MessageBox.Show(Klas[0].Naam.ToString());
```

Got an error on line `Klas[i].Naam = resultsKlas.Rows[i].ToString();` saying 'System.NullReferenceException'.

Comment: "*I tried alot allready but can't seem to find the correct answer*" - well, can you show some of your attempts and specify what's wrong with it? Then someone can show where your error is. Otherwise it looks like "write code for me, please" request.

Comment: What library do you use to access your database?

Comment: Note that the `WHERE ID = 1` part of your first example limits the set of database results to a single row, assuming it's a primary key (or a limited set, if it isn't)

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what `Klas` is, but supposing it is some array.

It looks like `Klas[0].Naam = KlasReader["Naam"].ToString();` is problem source. You're putting all results from query into the same variable.

It should be some list or another collection you're adding your query results to, not a single `Klas[0].Naam` variable.

For example (skipping irrelevant parts of your code)

```
var list = new List<KlasStruct>();
while (KlasReader.Read())
{
    var k = new KlasStruct();
    k.Naam = KlasReader["Naam"].ToString()
    list.Add(k);
}
```

And later (if you really need array, not list) you can transform list to array using `List.ToArray()` method.

Like this:

```
Klas = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm using structs like this:
struct KlasStruct
        {
          public string Naam;
          public int AantalUur;
        }
        KlasStruct[] Klas;

Comment: @Michieldepaepe In fact, it doent's change anything in the concept of my answer. But see the answer modified according to your conditions. Also note you need to create instance of your KlasStruct before assigning value to it's fields. It is the reason for you to get NullreferenceException when you're trying to `Klas[i].Naam = something` as in your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you may not know how many records there are in your database, you can use a list to fill from the database, and convert this list to an array:

```
        var klasList = new List<KlasStruct>();

        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Project Officieel\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project_MagnusCurriculum\Project.accdb";

           connect.Open();
           OleDbCommand cmdKlassen = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Naam FROM RichtingEnJaar WHERE ID = 1", connect);

           if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
           {    
               try
               {
                   OleDbDataReader KlasReader = null;
                   KlasReader = cmdKlassen.ExecuteReader();
                   while (KlasReader.Read())
                   {

                      klasList2.Add(new KlasStruct() { Naam = KlasReader["Naam"].ToString());
                   }
                   connect.Close();


                   Klas =  klasList.ToArray();
               }
               catch (Exception expe)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
                   connect.Close();
               }
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
          }
```

Comment: The problem is want to use something like a struct to do this:
struct KlasStruct
        {
          public string Naam;
          public int AantalUur;
        }
        KlasStruct[] Klas;

Comment: I have a klasStruct which containst a string and an integer. And the Klasstruct has to be an array

Comment: Why a struct? A struct is sometimes usefull for performance and/or API's